# Why Apache IoTDB reported if certain time series exists" after upgraded to Version 1.0.1?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask you guys a question. I am developing an Apache IoTDB client based on c#, and I called "CheckTimeSeriesExistsAsync" in 1.0.1 version. However, IoTDB reports an error: "`could not check if certain time series exists`". The code has not been changed, and the old version (V0.13) has no problem. Anyone know how to deal with this error?